# R round correlate function from corrr package

Tags: r, pearson-correlation

I'm creating a correlation table using the correlate function in the corrr package. Here is my code and a screenshot of the output.

```
correlation_table <- corrr::correlate(salary_professor_dataset_cor_table, 
                                      method = "pearson")
correlation_table
```

[image]

I think this would look better and be easier to read if I could round off the values in the correlation table. I tried this code:

```
correlation_table <- round(corrr::correlate(salary_professor_dataset_cor_table, 
                                      method = "pearson"),2)
```

But I get this error:

Error in Math.data.frame(list(term = c("prof_rank_factor", "yrs.since.phd", : non-numeric variable(s) in data frame: term

The non-numeric variables part of this error message doesn't make sense to me. When I look at the structure I only see integer or numeric variable types.

```
'data.frame':   397 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ prof_rank_factor : num  3 3 1 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ yrs.since.phd    : int  19 20 4 45 40 6 30 45 21 18 ...
 $ yrs.service      : int  18 16 3 39 41 6 23 45 20 18 ...
 $ salary           : num  139750 173200 79750 115000 141500 ...
 $ sex_factor       : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ discipline_factor: num  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

How can I clean up this correlation table with rounded values?

Comment: I wonder if you had tried `options(digits=2)` at the top side of your script?

Comment: Hi Manoj this is also TarJae's answer below. But I don't know what that options(digits=2) is doing? It looks like it's hanging code. Is that an instruction to a more global environment?

Comment: You are right. `options()` sets and configures the global settings. so by using `options(digits=2)` means you are setting digits to be rounded off to 2 places after decimal. you can read on `options()` by typing `?options` in the command prompt for invoking help on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use:

```
options(digits=2)
correlation_table <- corrr::correlate(salary_professor_dataset_cor_table, 
                                      method = "pearson")
correlation_table
```

Comment: can you help me understand what that options(digits=2) is doing? It looks like it's hanging code. Is that an instruction to a more global environment?

Comment: Allow the user to set and examine a variety of global options which affect the way in which R computes and displays its results. see `?options`

Answer (score 3):

After returning the `tibble` output with `correlate`, loop `across` the columns that are `numeric` and `round`

```
library(dplyr)
corrr::correlate(salary_professor_dataset_cor_table, 
                                  method = "pearson") %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), round, digits = 2))
```

Comment: This one gives me an error message I don't understand :/
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`. x non-numeric argument to mathematical function ℹ Input `..1` is `(function (.cols = everything(), .fns = NULL, ..., .names = NULL) ...`. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: thanks I see now what's happening. instead of mutate(across(everything() it's mutate(across(where(is.numeric)

Comment: @hachiko i was thinking that all the columns were numeric earlier.  sorry about that